# How to let two related arrays share the same operations by compact their iterators together

Tags: c++

Here's a simple example.

```
vector<string> name;
vector<int> age;
// name-age has a relationship
relatedIter ibegin(name.begin(),age.begin()), iend(name.end(),age.end());
std::remove_if(ibegin(),iend(),[](pair<string, int> deref){ return deref.second < 18;});
```

I managed to make it work for `std::remove_if`. But when I move on to `std::sort`, I failed.
Compiler complains that relatedIterRef do not match `std::swap(Ty_&,Ty_&)`.

```
struct relatedIterRef;
struct relatedIter {

    using difference_type = typename ptrdiff_t;
    using iterator_category = random_access_iterator_tag;
    using value_type = typename relatedIterRef;
    using pointer = typename relatedIterRef*;
    using reference = const relatedIterRef&;

    relatedIter(vector<int>::iterator i1, vector<int>::iterator i2) {
        iter1 = i1;
        iter2 = i2;
    }
    vector<int>::iterator iter1;
    vector<int>::iterator iter2;
    relatedIter& operator++() {
        iter1++;
        iter2++;
        return *this;
    }
    relatedIter& operator--() {
        iter1--;
        iter2--;
        return *this;
    }
    void operator=(const relatedIter& other) {
        iter1 = other.iter1;
        iter2 = other.iter2;
    }
    bool operator!=(const relatedIter& other) const {
        return iter1 != other.iter1;
    }
    bool operator<(const relatedIter& other) const {
        return iter1 < other.iter1;
    }
    bool operator==(const relatedIter& other) const {
        return iter1 == other.iter1;
    }
    difference_type operator-(const relatedIter& other) const {
        return iter1 - other.iter1;
    }
    relatedIter& operator+=(const difference_type _Off) {
        iter1+= _Off;
        iter2+= _Off;
        return *this;
    }
    relatedIter operator+(const difference_type _Off) {
        relatedIter tmp = *this;
        tmp.iter1 += _Off;
        tmp.iter2 += _Off;
        return tmp;
    }
    relatedIter& operator-=(const difference_type _Off) {
        iter1 -= _Off;
        iter2 -= _Off;
        return *this;
    }
    relatedIter operator-(const difference_type _Off) {
        relatedIter tmp = *this;
        tmp.iter1 -= _Off;
        tmp.iter2 -= _Off;
        return tmp;
    }
    relatedIterRef operator*() const;
};

using _Iter_diff_t = typename iterator_traits<relatedIter>::difference_type;

struct relatedIterRef: public relatedIter {
    relatedIterRef(vector<int>::iterator i1, vector<int>::iterator i2):relatedIter(i1,i2){
    }
    void operator=(const relatedIterRef& other)const {
        *iter1 = *other.iter1;
        *iter2 = *other.iter2;
    }
    bool operator<(const relatedIterRef& other)const {
        return *iter1 < *other.iter1;
    }
    operator pair<int, int>() {
        return { *iter1,*iter2 };
    }
};

relatedIterRef relatedIter:: operator*() const {
    return relatedIterRef(iter1, iter2);
}
```

Is there a way that make it work for `std::sort`, or even every algorithm?
Note: I don't want to put it in a struct and sort it like below:

```
struct People{
string name;
int age;
}
```

Because in practice my two arrays contain "useful data" and "intermediate that should be deleted".
I don't want to waste performance.

Comment: [`views::zip`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view)?

Comment: @康桓瑋  It seems to be what I want. But I can't try this now because I'm working on a C++17 project.

Comment: @zyr https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3